# How to add peers after Hyperledger Fabric is launched

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I would like to add peers, after Hyperledger fabric network got up.
I learned from [this site](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/configtxupdate/README.md) that configtxlator tool can do it.
Is it only possible with this tool?
kindly let me know if there is alternative method to add peer without using configtxlator tool.

Comment: Could you define what do you mean when you ask about "adding peers"? Where do you want to add a peer, to a channel or for an organization?

Answer (score 2):

The configtxlator can update a configuration of a channel.
This can be used for adding new organizations.

In order to add new peers to an existing organization you need to generate new certificates for your peers and sign them using the key of the root CA certs f the existing organizations - Configtxlator won't help you in this aspect.